# Construct Binary Tree from Parent Array test case failing

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Link of the question-[Link][1]

Basically we are given an array of integers and it's size. Question is to construct a binary tree from it. Each index corresponds to data stored in a node, and the value of that index is the data of the parent. Value of the root node index would always be -1 as there is no parent for root. The Output will be the sorted level order traversal of the tree.

Now my approach is that I parse the array from 1 to n(not the 0th element/root node), and for each element, I get it's parent using the first function, and insert the child accordingly. But one particular test case is failing. Maybe the website's own output is not correct. I will post everything below:-

***Example test case-***

Size of array-7

Elements-  -1 0 0 1 1 3 5

Output-  0 1 2 3 4 5 6

***Particular test case(which is my doubt)-***

Size of array- 42

Elements-
3 19 1 41 35 29 27 11 17 23 9 15 33 13 39 23 19 25 21 1 33 15 31 21 5 7 37 29 7 11 31 39 -1 27 3 9 25 17 13 41 37 35

Website's output- 32

My output - 0

Functions

```
void getParent(Node* root, int val, Node* &main)
{
    if(root==NULL) return;
    if(root->data==val){
        main=root;
        return;
    }
    getParent(root->left,val,main);
    getParent(root->right,val,main);
    
}

Node *createTree(int parent[], int n)
{
    if(n==0) return NULL;
    Node * root=new Node(0);
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        Node* main=NULL;
        getParent(root,parent[i],main);
        //main has the parent
        
        Node* child=new Node(i);
        if(main==NULL) break;
        
        
        if(main->left==NULL)
        {
            main->left=child;
        }
        else if(main->right==NULL)
        {
            main->right=child;
        }
    }
    return root;
} 


  [1]: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-a-binary-tree-from-parent-array-representation/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fRmn.png
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your description of the tree is unclear. Could you give an example of an input array, the desired tree and the output number? *(Not* a link, post the example in the Question itself.)

Comment: I think I see a failure case for your code: `{1,-1}`

Comment: What does the output of 32 mean?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Same is my question. I am not understanding how are they printing 32 even though it is not present in the array.

Comment: @Beta I posted an example along with the output condition in the 1st paragraph. Please have a look.

Comment: I think I see the problem. But something appears to be wrong with the "particular" test case; it doesn't look like a tree at all... The output should be the value in the root node, which is where the `32` comes from. In the case of `{1, 5, 5, 2, 2, -1, 3}`, the output should be 5.

Comment: @Beta Okay I was assuming a very wrong thing that the 1st element of array will always be the root, which is not true for every test case. But the case you mentioned,{1, 5, 5, 2, 2, -1, 3}, the output for that one is 5 1 2 0 3 4 6.(I checked with the website's given solution.) In this case, elements at index 1 and 2 are 5, which leaves 5 having both children to be printed, and so on.

Comment: Note the problem is that you will not be able to get the value of the leaf nodes, usually we store the value of the node, not it's parent.... please fix your logic problems @TITICHHMISHRA

Comment: @KennyOstrom I didn't write it properly(really sorry for that) but it is written there that the element with value -1 will be root node, and we to return the root after building the entire tree as per the array. The issue was solved because I was missing something which was mentioned out by Beta. Thanks for the reply though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing with your `getParent` method. Also you are initiating a root node with value 0 and not doing anywith it in the loop and then finally you return the root. I suspect your root will always have a value 0.

The solution is very simple actually. You initialize an array of nodes with each node's value as the index of the array. For example for an array of size 5, you create an array of 5 nodes with each node having a value of the index at which it is located.

Then next step is go through the `parent` array and see if the node located at `parent[i]` has either `left` or `right` "available", if yes assign the node accordingly.

the code is :

```
Node* createTree(int parent[], int n) {
  Node** nodes = new Node*[n];
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
      nodes[i] = new Node(i);
  int rootIndex = 0;
  for ( int i  = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    if ( parent[i] == -1 ) {
      rootIndex = i;
    } else {
      if ( nodes[parent[i]] -> left == NULL ) {
        nodes[parent[i]] -> left = nodes[i];
      } else if ( nodes[parent[i]] -> right == NULL ) {
          nodes[parent[i]] -> right = nodes[i];
      }
    }
    
  }
  return nodes[rootIndex];
}
```

Comment: At that time, I was thinking that the 1st element of array will always be the root, which I realized later shouldn't be true for every case.

Comment: yeah, the question was slightly confusing.